# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

i am new to android development , here i am trying to create a simple database app using sqlite
what i am trying to do is when the user selects search it will ask for the id and the corresponding data matching the id should replace the fields of editText by that particular data

ActivityMain.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ashish.project.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Personal Details"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="center" />
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="First Name" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText_LastName"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Last Name" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText_number"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:hint="Contact Number" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText_email"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:hint="E-mail" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Submit Details"
                android:id="@+id/Button_Submit"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Show Details"
                android:id="@+id/button_Show_Details"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_row="5"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button_search"
                android:layout_below="@id/Button_Submit"
                android:text="search"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Clear Table"
                android:id="@+id/button_clear"
                android:gravity="left|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button_Show_Details"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </GridLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText_srch"
        android:hint="Enter id to search"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="search"
        android:id="@+id/button_show_id_result"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
   package com.example.ashish.project;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button_submit,button_show_details,button_clear,button_search,button_show_id_result;
    EditText firstName,lastName,number,email,editText_id_search;
    String firstnameString,lastnameString,emailString,num;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button_submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button_Submit);
        button_show_id_result=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_show_id_result);
        editText_id_search=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_srch);
        button_show_details=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Show_Details);
        firstName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button_search=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_search);
        button_clear=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_clear);
        lastName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_LastName);
        number=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_number);
        email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_email);

        editText_id_search.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button_show_id_result.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        button_clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                db.clear();
            }
        });



        button_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
/*
*/
                editText_id_search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button_show_id_result.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                button_show_id_result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String  qry = editText_id_search.getText().toString();
                        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                        db.search(qry);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        button_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                firstnameString = firstName.getText().toString();
                lastnameString=lastName.getText().toString();
                num=number.getText().toString();
                emailString=email.getText().toString();

                DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                db.insertData(firstnameString,lastnameString,num,emailString);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Record Updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(email.getWindowToken(),0);
                firstName.setText("");
                lastName.setText("");
                number.setText("");
                email.setText("");

                db.close();

            }
        });

        button_show_details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,List_Result.class);

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }



    public void show(String string, String cString, String s, String string1) {

        firstName.setText(string);
        lastName.setText(cString);
        number.setText(s);
        email.setText(string1);
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
package com.example.ashish.project;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by ashis on 7/21/2016.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;
    private static String DATABSE_NAME="DATA";
    private static String TABLE_NAME="PERSONAL_INFORMATION";
    private static String COLUMN_ID= "_ID";
    private static String COLUMN_FIRST_NAME="FIRST_NAME";
    private static String COLUMN_LAST_NAME="LAST_NAME";
    private static String COLUMN_NUMBER = "NUMBER";
    private static String COLUMN_EMAIL="EMAIL";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABSE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME + "( "
                                + COLUMN_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                                + COLUMN_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT, "
                                + COLUMN_LAST_NAME + " TEXT, "
                                + COLUMN_NUMBER + " TEXT , "
                                + COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT"+" )";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME);
        this.onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
        
    }


    public void insertData(String firstnameString, String lastnameString, String num, String emailString) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_FIRST_NAME,firstnameString);
        values.put(COLUMN_LAST_NAME,lastnameString);
        values.put(COLUMN_NUMBER,num);
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL,emailString);
        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> readData() {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String readQry = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(readQry,null);
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                list.add(c.getString(0)+ ": "+c.getString(1) +" "+ c.getString(2)+","+c.getString(3)+","+c.getString(4));


            }while (c.moveToNext());

        }
        c.close();
        db.close();



        return list;

    }

    public void clear() {
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        String clrqry = "DROP TABLE " + TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(clrqry);

        this.onCreate(db);

    }

    public void search(String srch) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();
        String sqlqry = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME +"  WHERE  "+ COLUMN_ID + " = ?";
        Cursor c=    db.rawQuery(sqlqry,new  String[]{srch});
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {

                        obj.show(c.getString(1),c.getString(2),c.getString(3),c.getString(4));
            }
            while (c.moveToNext());
        }

    }
}
```

Activity_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ashish.project.List_Result">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity_list.java

```
package com.example.ashish.project;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class List_Result extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listview1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list__result);
        listview1=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);


        loadlistviewData();
    }

    private void loadlistviewData() {


        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        ArrayList<String> list = db.readData();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listview1.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

here is the logcat when i try to click Search after inputting id

```
07-25 14:27:34.033 668-668/com.example.ashish.project W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.ashish.project-2/lib/arm
07-25 14:27:34.256 668-668/com.example.ashish.project W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-25 14:27:34.541 668-668/com.example.ashish.project D/android.widget.GridLayout: vertical constraints: y4-y0>=864, y4-y3<=192, y3-y2<=91, y2-y1<=91, y1-y0<=100 are inconsistent; permanently removing: y4-y3<=192. 
07-25 14:27:39.235 668-668/com.example.ashish.project D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-25 14:27:39.236 668-668/com.example.ashish.project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.ashish.project, PID: 668
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.example.ashish.project.MainActivity.show(MainActivity.java:103)
                                                                            at com.example.ashish.project.DatabaseHelper.search(DatabaseHelper.java:108)
                                                                            at com.example.ashish.project.MainActivity$2$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:60)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText`

Comment: Is occur on your `button_submit' onclick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call **show()** by creating a new Instance of MainActivity. Hence all the variables of MainActivity will be null. Better you should make those static so that initialization of those views will be same for all instances of MainActivity. Try

```
static EditText firstName,lastName,number,email,editText_id_search;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use static for your View widget.

Replace your search function in DatabaseHelper.java with below one:

```
public void search(String srch, MainActivity activity) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String sqlqry = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME +"  WHERE  "+ COLUMN_ID + " = ?";
    Cursor c=    db.rawQuery(sqlqry,new  String[]{srch});
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {

                    activity.show(c.getString(1),c.getString(2),c.getString(3),c.getString(4));
        }
        while (c.moveToNext());
    }

}
```

In MainActivity.java, replace below:

```
db.search(qry);
```

With:

```
db.search(qry, MainActivity.this);
```

Answer (score -1):

just wrap with try and catch it solves the problem.